# How to add this unallocated space to ubuntu partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

Ok so my situation is a little bit different.  I'm relatively new to Ubuntu so I'm not figuring out how to add the unallocated space to the Ubuntu partition so I can make it bigger?  The other ntfs files are for Windows 10 so I can't delete them.  I appreciate any help.  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the running OS it doesn't work.
Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
When on Live desktop open GParted.

Move `sda3` to the left.
Move `sda4` to the left.
Grow the size of `sda4` (add the free space).
Grow the size of `sda5` (add the free space).

Maybe you have to reinstall the Windows boot loader afterwards.
After having done this you have to reinstall the GRUB boot loader.
Maybe you also will have to edit the `fstab` file afterwards as well.
But all these additional things at least would be another question.

Note :

I tried to explain as simple as possible to make it easier for you to understand the general topic.

Comment: Worked Perfectly!!!  Don't need to reinstall anything!  All works just fine.  Thank you very much!